# How to find any non-digit characters using RegEx in ABAP

Tags: regex, abap

I need a Regular Expression to check whether a value contains any other characters than digits between 0 and 9.

I also want to check the length of the value.

The RegEx I´ve made: **^([0-9]\d{6})$**

My test value is: 123Z45 and 123456

The ABAP code:

```
FIND ALL OCCURENCES OF REGEX '^([0-9]\d{6})$' IN L_VALUE RESULTS DATA(LT_RESULTS).
```

I´m expecting a result in `LT_RESULTS`, when I´m testing the first test value '123Z45', because there is a non-digit character.

But `LT_RESULTS` is in nearly every test case empty.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your expression `^([0-9]\d{6})$` translates to:

- `^` - start of input
- `(` - begin capture group

  - `[0-9]` - a character between 0 and 9
  - `\d{6}` - six digits (digit = character between 0 and 9)
- `)` - end capture group
- `$` - end of input

So it will only match `1234567` (7 digit strings), not `123456`, or `123Z45`.

If you just need to find a string that contains non digits you could use the following instead: `^\d*[^\d]+\d*$`

- `*` - previous element may occur zero, one or more times
- `[^\d]` - `^` right after `[` means "NOT", i.e. any character which is not a digit
- `+` - previous element may occur one or more times

Example:

```js
const expression = /^\d*[^\d]+\d*$/;
const inputs = ['123Z45', '123456', 'abc', 'a21345', '1234f', '142345'];

console.log(inputs.filter(i => expression.test(i)));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this [character class](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_753_index_htm/7.53/en-US/abenregex_syntax_signs.htm#@@ITOC@@ABENREGEX_SYNTAX_SIGNS_7) if you want to extract non-digit group:

```
DATA(l_guid) = '0074162D8EAA549794A4EF38D9553990680B89A1'.

DATA(regx) = '[[:alpha:]]+'.

DATA(substr) = match( val   = l_guid
                      regex = regx
                      occ   = 1 ).
```

It finds a first occured non-digit group of characters and shows it.

If you want to just check if they are exists or how much of them reside in your string, count built-in function is your friend:

```
DATA(how_many) = count( val = l_guid regex = regx ).

DATA(yes) = boolc( count( val = l_guid regex = regx ) > 0 ).
```

[Match](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_750_index_htm/7.50/en-US/index.htm?file=abenmatch_functions.htm) and [count](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_750_index_htm/7.50/en-US/index.htm?file=abencount_functions.htm) exist since ABAP 7.50.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need a Regular Expression for something more complex, ABAP has some nice comparison operators CO (Contains Only), CA, NA etc for you. Something like:

```
IF L_VALUE CO '0123456789' AND STRLEN( L_VALUE ) = 6.
```